# Not able to publish a message to queue in RabbitMQ using it's HTTP API

Tags: rest, rabbitmq

I am using the REST API `http://192.168.99.100:32787/api/exchanges/%2f/amq.direct/publish`
to publish a message to my `helloworld.q` queue.

**Payload:**

```
{"properties":{},"routing_key":"","payload":"Hello World","payload_encoding":"string"}
```

I have not created any new exchanges. I wasn't sure which exchange to specify hence used `amq.direct` in the rest url. I have already provided the Basic Auth credentials and I am getting following response from the API.

```
{
    "routed": false
}
```

Not sure what's wrong.

The latest documentation on how to use it's HTTP API can be found here.
https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_11/priv/www/api/index.html

Comment: Nothing in your request or properties indicates the queue to which the message should be published. How did you ever expect it to work with a direct exchange?!?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two ways to make that work:

- Either you use the default exchange and specify your queue name as routing key (otherwise RabbitMQ has no clue regarding which queue you want your message to go):

  `POST /api/exchanges/%2f//publish HTTP/1.1
  {"properties":{},"routing_key":"helloworld.q","payload":"Hello World","payload_encoding":"string"}`
- Or you explicitly send it to the `amq.direct` exchange but then you have to create a binding between `helloworld.q` and `amq.direct` before publishing the message. The routing key of the message you publish will have to match the one you specify on the binding too.

Comment: This didn't work for me because the queue didn't already exist.  ;)